# Passing data with CCNotficationCenter

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am new to Cocos2d-X.

```
CCNotificationCenter::sharedNotificationCenter()->addObserver(
            this,
            callfuncO_selector(test::printSomething),
            "hello",
            NULL);
```

and the callback function is

```
void PingoScreen::printSomething(CCObject *pObject) {
    CCString * myData = (CCString*)pObject;
    CCLog("The data posted is %s",myData);
}
```

Now i want to send a CCString parameter via notification  so that

```
CCNotificationCenter::sharedNotificationCenter()->postNotification("hello",
                ccs(notificationData));
```

How can i do this ? What do i need to change in the notification definition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Register Notification**

```
CCNotificationCenter::sharedNotificationCenter()->addObserver(this, callfuncO_selector(GameScene::doSomething), "eventNotification", NULL);
```

**Remove Notification**

```
CCNotificationCenter::sharedNotificationCenter()->removeObserver(this, "eventNotification");
```

**Post Notification**

```
CCNotificationCenter::sharedNotificationCenter()->postNotification("eventNotification", myString);
```

**Callback method**

```
void GameScene::doSomething(CCObject *pObject) {
    CCString *myString = (CCString*)pObject;

    // XXX: Do something
}
```

Comment: What does the last NULL mean in the Register Notification code ?

Comment: The extra object parameter in addObserver works as a filter. If set to an object, then only notifications that are sent by this sender will be delivered to the observer. If set NULL, then all notifications of this type will be delivered to the observer.