# pass std:string by notificationcenter in cocos2d-x v3?

Tags: cocos2d-x, notificationcenter

can someone tell me how to pass std:string by notificationcenter in cocos2d-x v3 ?
thanks

NotificationCenter::getInstance()->postNotification("DISPLAY_GAME_OVER", ????);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing data with CCNotficationCenter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537329/passing-data-with-ccnotficationcenter)

Comment: Note: convert your std::string to CCString

Comment: Without looking, I think it takes a `Ref*` so what @LearnCocos2D says about converting your `std::string` to a `cocos2d::Value` should work.

Comment: @GameDeveloper I use cocos2d::Value but it get error. cocos2d:Value ss("something"); NotificationCenter::getInstance()->postNotification("DISPLAY_GAME_OVER", ss); <- error at ss

Comment: lemme look in the morning.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D that is way for cocos2d V2

Comment: So I'm wrong, Looking at the API Doc you want to pass in the string and a a pointer to the object posting the notification. So in your example above: `NotificationCenter::getInstance()->postNotification("DISPLAY_GAME_OVER", this);`